# Windows Google Chrome doesn't show validation popup for required checkbox on form submit

Tags: html, google-chrome, validation

Windows Google Chrome doesn't show validation popup for required checkbox on form submit. Chrome for MacOS works fine
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pk01oybr/)

```
<form action="/">
<label for=x>Hello</label>
<input type=checkbox id=x required>
<button type=submit> click me</button>
</form>
```

Does anyone know a workaround?

tested on Google Chrome for Windows Version 96.0.4664.45 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: The same issue is on MacOS Chrome Version 96.0.4664.110 (Official Build) (x86_64). The popup is shown after moving cursor away from the submit button.